# How to destroy previous page in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make a login page in flutter, where when the login succeed, the app switches to the next page and destroy the previous one, i.e. once the user is logged in, the only way for him to go back to the login page is to explicitly logout from the current session, instead of only pressing the previous button of the android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `Navigator.push`, use another option like `Navigator.pushReplacement` or `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`

Comment: Is there any way other than this?

Comment: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete what Rémi said, if you want to make sure that there is no other view before the home view, you should do that:

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, YourMaterialPageRoute(), (e) => false);
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: The previous page does not get destroyed. The state is INTACT when I reroute back to it from say another page

Comment: How do you manage the state of your view? Mb create another question (with a reproducible example) on Stack and give me the link here :)

Comment: Okay. Will do that

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick tip if you're using routes in your material app and Navigating by screen name you can use:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, newRouteName, (route) => false)
```

Comment: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: @CarlosPeñaranda looks like you sent the wrong datatype, ensure you are using String. Like the err message states.